# Jquery UI dialog box is not working

Tags: html, jquery-ui, dialog

Here is my code. If I use only one dialog box then its works fine, More than one is not working. Please help me to solve this.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
   
 $('#bouncer-1').click(function(){
    $( "#xyz" ).dialog();
 });

    $('#bouncer-2').click(function(){
    $( "#zyx" ).dialog();
 });
 
  });
```

```html
<div id="stage">
<div id="traveler-1">
<div id="bouncer-1"></div>
</div>
<div id="traveler-2">
<div id="bouncer-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="xyz" title="Hello">
Hello Im xyz..
</div>
<div id="zyx" title="Hello">
Hello,Im zyx..
</div>
```

Comment: Providing a JSFiddle could help because right now it is tricky to really help you. Did you import jQuery-ui properly ? Do you have any javascript error message in your console ? Is the click event properly triggered (if div are width: 0px and height : 0px not easy to click on it :D. Can you be more specifiic about "not working"

Answer (score 0):

Element `ID` should be unique thats why its name is `ID`. Change `ID`s to different one like this:

Hello Im xyz..



Hello,Im zyx..

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
   
 $('#bouncer-1').click(function(){
    $( "#xyz1" ).dialog();
 });

    $('#bouncer-2').click(function(){
    $( "#zyx2" ).dialog();
 });
 
  });
```

```html
<div id="stage">
<div id="traveler-1">
<div id="bouncer-1"></div>
</div>
<div id="traveler-2">
<div id="bouncer-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="xyz1" title="Hello">
Hello Im xyz..
</div>
<div id="zyx2" title="Hello">
Hello,Im zyx..
</div>
```

Comment: xyz !== zyx but agree with you those are terrible names for debugging/testing :D

Comment: @sebastienbarbier ha ha :D  Well, these are not mine.

Comment: Actually i used different IDs only, i just give this for example.Still Its not working . If add second dialog the first one is not opening, without second first works fine.

Comment: @AjithMaverick it would be great if you make fidler

Comment: @AjithMaverick  it is not js issue. It must be css issue. Most of the time, first div overlaps second one while animating. Look this https://jsfiddle.net/samirkumardas/hcmyjfwt/1/ where I have delayed animation and working fine